# Beamer: Vertical space before block

Tags: beamer

I want to remove the space before block environment only when the frame starts with a block environment.

My current block environment starts as below.

```
\defbeamertemplate*{block begin}{}
{
    \par\removelastskip\vskip\medskipamount
```

But, I want to remove that `\vskip\medskipamount` automatically when the block is used as

```
\begin{frame}
    % remove the vertical space here
    \begin{block}
        some content
    \end{block}
    % don't remove the vertical space here
    \begin{block}
        some content
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
```